# OpenGL ES 2.0 modify shader variable

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, shader

I thought you could modify a Uniform variable and then use this method to get the variable after draw but it throws a cannot modify uniform exception when building the shader.

glGetUniformfv(PROGRAM_INT, UNIFORM_INT, PARAMS, 0);

I want the shader to modify a variable and return that variable?

Is there a way to modify a shaders variable, and a use a GL method to get that variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Uniform variables are read-only in the shader code. They are used to pass values from your Java/C++ client code to the shader code, and not the other way.

In ES 2.0, the only way I can think of to get values that were produced by the shader back into the client code is to produce them as color values in the fragment shader output. They will then be part of the framebuffer content, which you can read back with `glReadPixels()`.

In newer versions of OpenGL ES, as well as in recent versions of full OpenGL, there are additional options. For example, ES 3.1 introduces [Shader Storage Buffers](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Shader_Storage_Buffer_Object), which are also available in OpenGL 4.3 and later. They allow shaders to write values to buffers, which you could read back from client code.